# How do I cutout shapes from a JS banner?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am currently working on a PSD (pictured below) for a client and am looking for guidance on how to cut specific shapes from a JS slider. My initial thought process is to overlay css shapes at the bottom of the banner to get the desired effect, as shown in the picture.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to that method. I've looked around on the internet but can't find much info on what I'm trying to accomplish.

All advice welcomed. Thank you in advance.

[image: cucode custom theme]

Comment: try using svg images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use viewport width to achieve this objective. I hope it is helpful to you.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
  background: #000;
}

.box:before
{
 border-top:80px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50vw solid #fff;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.box:after
{
 border-top:80px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50vw solid #fff;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! I had no clue this was even possible using a view-port width. 

http://numberonedesigns.com/test/

Comment: Thanks you. :-  )

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) tool for creating CSS clip-paths.

One example would be:

```css
.container {
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```